# How to add dynamically add comments to a PDF using XFDF

Tags: pdf

I am sending users xfdf data to prepopulate PDFs on my site.

But I also want to add comments which can differ for different situations.  The comments are to help the users populate some of the fields by providing some data they can use to paste into the fields.

I used a comment from an existing pdf, exported this as xfdf as a template but the problem is that when I create the xfdf with this, a security message from Acrobat Reader pops up saying "The comments could not be imported because the document's permissions do not allow comment import operations." ... but there are no security restrictions on the document.

This happens on other PCs, but not the one I created it ... but that one has Acrobat Pro.

So, what's the correct way of dynamically creating comments?

***ok, solved it .... the PDF has to have user rights enabled in order for Acrobat Reader to see the comments.  See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.html***

Comment: I got problem in adding xfdf fields.. I need your help

Comment: Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083616/unable-to-merge-xfdf-file-to-pdf

Comment: sorry, never used the iText library ...

Comment: Can you please share what have you used...post any alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it .... the PDF has to have user rights enabled in order for Acrobat Reader to see the comments. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.html